# How to allow .NET auto-generated inline JavaScript to be executed, using Content Security Policy?

Tags: javascript, .net, iis, content-security-policy

I am creating a web site using .NET. Now I have set up my Content-Security-Policy and mostly works fine and I separated all inline JS in individual files. The problem I am facing is that .NET or IIS (not sure of the culprit) but the web server does some autogeneration of JS code, as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ctl13', 'ctl01', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>
```

But the is also few other blocks of code...

This raises a "Refused to execute" error. And I am not sure how to approach this. Could I use Subresource Integrity, with this generated script? I also cannot use third party libraries. :(

Answer (score -1):

Well after some searching and trying I realized I can copy the Sha1 + hash from the Inspector in Chrome, simply inside the "script-src" as the value:

```
script-src 'self' https: 'sha256-2vr5KadqwtMK7a+bOf/ned/cPnF2yNooMulXA8E65wGw=' 'sha256-uotn9EGEf58Cz/Xefuk7l1rlYusddaEDcJMklItXhgs=' 'sha256-uYoAmCrBFM4tx/Ww+6eFuIJxuwZ3YasdWUTlgnPuE=';
```

Seems everything works this way. I do have another concern now. 
When I will move my build to the production server (I cannot access it right now) will this hashes still work fine?